# make alias available to process created by sh

Tags: bash, shell, subprocess, alias

I added below two aliases in my .bash_profile :-

```
alias hey="echo 'Hey from machine'"
alias callHey="sh ~/playground/octagon/shellExamples/heyScript.sh"
```

Code of heyScript.sh :-

```
hey
```

Please find below result, when hey and callHey are called :-

```
~ $

hey
Hey from machine

~ $

callHey
/Users/mogli/playground/octagon/shellExamples/heyScript.sh: line 1: hey: command not found
```

**hey** alias is not available in the process created by **sh**.

How to make these aliases available in the process created by sh.

Note : I don't have a option to convert alias to function and export it using **export -f**

Comment: Did you try using `${BASH_ALIASES[hey]}` as found here [https://askubuntu.com/a/631108](https://askubuntu.com/a/631108) ?

Comment: Since you are using `bash`, could you alias `callHey` with `bash` instead of `sh`?

Comment: tried alias callHey="bash ~/playground/octagon/shellExamples/heyScript.sh", but it didn't worked